# Salesforce validation Formula error Validation Invalid (null)

Tags: validation-rule

I have crated the following formula

```
AND(
    ISPICKVAL(Lived_Since__c, "- 0-24 months"),
    ISBLANK(Previous_Address__c)
)
```

for the scenario if the lived since field has a value of - 0-24 months
then it will show the error message

> Please fill the field named Privious address

but I am getting error

> Validation Formula "Require_Previous_Address" Invalid (null)

Even I fill this info in the Previous address or not.
I think this is correct formula.
For testing I have changed this formula to following.

```
AND(
    ISPICKVAL(Lived_Since__c, "- 0-24 months"),
    ISNULL(Previous_Address__c)
)
```

and still getting the same error.

Comment: Please share your field type and Picklist Value API name. Add some screenshot of example. These details will help in answer

Comment: Are you getting this error message when you're trying to _save_ this validation rule, or when you're trying to save a record? What is the error message that you've configured your validation rule to show? (this will be in a text box underneath the one where you enter the formula)

Comment: @DerekF I think he is getting error during record save.

Comment: Yes I am getting the error When I try to save the record.@A.K

Comment: is `Previous_Address__c` a compound custom address field?  Is it encrypted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compound Address contains group of field Like `City`, `Street`, `Country`. You need to add Logic on sub-field which is part of Compound Address field.

[image: Compound Address Field]

This is the way we can apply validation rule for validation field.

[image: Validation Field]

This is the way we can create Validation Rule.

[image: Validation Rule]

Reference: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.fields_caf_requirements.htm&type=5

[image: Compound Address Field Limit]